# in relation many to many is included a lot of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, sqlite

I have a many to many relation between two tables in my database, so in my edmx model I have only two tables, no the intermediate table. This tables are Movies and Genres.

When I search for some movies, I get also the related entities, so with eager loading I populate the collection Genres of my entities Movies. Is what I want.

The problem is that when in the result has more than one movie, the collection Genres of the entities MOvies are populated, but also the collection Movies of the entities Genres are populated. So when I send to the repository one movie to be updated, if I attach the the entity to the context, I attach this movie and all the movies that have the same genres that the movie that I want to update. This is because in the genres of the entities are included the movies that are of the same genres than the movie that I want to update.

So if in my first search I get a lot of movies, when I want to update one movie I send a lot of entities that I don't need to seed, so it is a lot of traffic in the network.

is there any way that when I search for results the collection of movies in the genres entities are not populated? Because I only populate the related entities of my main entity, movies, not all of them.

I am using SQLite and EF 4.4; and I try to find the mergeOption to disabled the tracking of the genres, but I don't find it.

Thanks.

Comment: "*I send a lot of entities*"..."*it is a lot of traffic in the network*": Where do you **send** entities to and what is this traffic on the network? Between EF client and database no entities are sent at all, just SQL statements and column/row data. The amount of those data does not change if the inverse navigation properties are populated or not. Or do you mean with *"network"* that you move an entity graph across a (web) service boundary or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are designing entities and relationships (logical design), you can describe a many-to-many relationship between two entities. When you need to implement these entities and their relationship in a database (physical design), you can't do it with only two tables; you really need an intermediate table to express the relationship.

A one-to-many relationship between two entities only needs a table for each entity (simple foreign key relationship). So, if your genres table was simply a list of genres for a given movie, it would be a one-to-many (movie as parent, genres as child); that would work.

However, since you've described genres to be in a many-to-many relationship with movies, it suggests that genres is to be used to supply a sort of "pick list" i.e. one row in genres is not related to any specific row in movies, but could be related to any movie (and vice-versa). To make this relationship work, you need an intermediate table, let's call it "moviegenres" which need only contain two columns - a foreign key relating to movies' primary key, and a foreign key relating to genre's primary key. This table is actually expressing your many-to-many relationship, and assigning genres to movies is then effected by adding rows to "moviegenres".

Before you can consider any issues with how your data is populating, you need to resolve the logical-to-physical design issue first.

Comment: Yes, in my database I have three tables, the two mentioned and the moviesgenres as intermediate table, only with the FK of both tables. So when So I have only two entities, Movies and Genres but not moviesGenres. I have a collection o genres in the entities of movies an vice-versa. The problem is that EF when execute the query, populate all the collections. EF populates the collection of genres in movies and in genres populates the collection of movies. So one movie has a collection of genres that has collection of movies with movies.So I send a lot of entities when I only wnat to update one.